# Split Multiple Json Javascript

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, json, jsp

I have Json Like Below,

```
var json = [{"AVGDUR":1,"USERNAME":"usera","NAME":"name2","TOTALDOC":1}][{"AVGDUR":12,"USERNAME":"userb","NAME":"nameb","TOTALDOC":2}][{"AVGDUR":1.52,"USERNAME":"userc","NAME":"namec","TOTALDOC":617}][{"AVGDUR":2.41,"USERNAME":"userd","NAME":"named","TOTALDOC":167}][{"AVGDUR":1.65,"USERNAME":"usere","NAME":"namee","TOTALDOC":20}][{"AVGDUR":10,"USERNAME":"userf","NAME":"namef","TOTALDOC":1}][{"AVGDUR":0.46,"USERNAME":"userg","NAME":"nameg","TOTALDOC":143}]
```

Now I want to split it into 7 JSON objects for each key, like below.

> var splitA
>   =[{"AVGDUR":1,"USERNAME":"usera","NAME":"name2","TOTALDOC":1}]
>   var splitB =
>   [{"AVGDUR":12,"USERNAME":"userb","NAME":"nameb","TOTALDOC":2}]
>   var splitC =
>   [{"AVGDUR":1.52,"USERNAME":"userc","NAME":"namec","TOTALDOC":617}]
>   var splitD =
>   [{"AVGDUR":2.41,"USERNAME":"userd","NAME":"named","TOTALDOC":167}]
>   var splitE =
>   [{"AVGDUR":1.65,"USERNAME":"usere","NAME":"namee","TOTALDOC":20}]
>   var splitF =
>   [{"AVGDUR":10,"USERNAME":"userf","NAME":"namef","TOTALDOC":1}]
>   var splitG = [{"AVGDUR":0.46,"USERNAME":"userg","NAME":"nameg","TOTALDOC":143}]

How can I do with javascript?

Comment: Is it me or the they are both the same?

Comment: its different, i want the fisrt is multiple json and be 1 json, and i want to split them

Comment: They are the same. And btw, both data are not valid json structure.

Comment: Yup...the same...problem solved I guess. You had what you wanted all along.

Comment: I'm sorry, this is edited json format

Comment: @MakanKrayon I added answer to the post. I hope it will work as per your expectation.

Answer (score 1):

First of all this json format is not valid. You should use a json validator to check your string if not sure.(for example https://jsonlint.com/)
A json object should be inside braces {}.
Each propery:value pair should be comma separated.If you have an array inside your object, it should be inside brackets [].
So in your example, which is an array out of objects you should have an opening bracket in the beginning and a closing one in the end. Inside the braces all your objects should have a comma (,) after each closing brace (}).

Then you can take these objects with a lot of ways.
For example you can check your json String char by char and keep track of the indexes of each opening and closing brace, and then take substrings with the proper indexes.

However there are Json Parsers to help you do your job but your format should be valid in order for them to work.

Answer (score 1):

**Few observations :**

- `JSON` provided by you is not a valid `JSON`.
- It should be an `array of objects` not a multiple arrays.

**Solution as per the requirement :**

```js
var json = [{
 "AVGDUR": 1,
 "USERNAME": "usera",
 "NAME": "name2",
 "TOTALDOC": 1
}, {
 "AVGDUR": 12,
 "USERNAME": "userb",
 "NAME": "nameb",
 "TOTALDOC": 2
}, {
 "AVGDUR": 1.52,
 "USERNAME": "userc",
 "NAME": "namec",
 "TOTALDOC": 617
}, {
 "AVGDUR": 2.41,
 "USERNAME": "userd",
 "NAME": "named",
 "TOTALDOC": 167
}, {
 "AVGDUR": 1.65,
 "USERNAME": "usere",
 "NAME": "namee",
 "TOTALDOC": 20
}, {
 "AVGDUR": 10,
 "USERNAME": "userf",
 "NAME": "namef",
 "TOTALDOC": 1
}, {
 "AVGDUR": 0.46,
 "USERNAME": "userg",
 "NAME": "nameg",
 "TOTALDOC": 143
}];

for (var i in json) {
  console.log("var " + json[i].USERNAME + " = " , [json[i]]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So ignoring the people that don't understand the problem of streaming and getting chunks of JSON that are just consecutive, this is something I wrote for that exact problem (written in Typescript for a ReadableStream `pipeThrough(jsonDecoderStream())`, but the logic should be obvious-ish) -

```
/**
 * For streaming JSON encoded data, use the generic to set the decoded type.
 *
 * NOTE: This can (currently) only handle "string", {object} and [array] types!
 */
export function jsonDecoderStream<T extends object>() {
    // Cache everything so we don't parse through the same part of the string multiple times
    let buffer = "";
    let index = 0;
    let curlyCount = 0;
    let squareCount = 0;
    let inString = false;
    let escapeCount = 0;

    return new TransformStream<Uint8Array, T>({
        transform(chunk, controller) {
            buffer += chunk;

            for (; index < buffer.length; index++) {
                const char = buffer[index];

                if (inString) {
                    switch (char) {
                        case "\\":
                            escapeCount++;
                            break;
                        case "\"":
                            if (escapeCount % 2 === 1) {
                                inString = false;
                            }
                        // Deliberate fallthrough
                        default:
                            escapeCount = 0;
                            break;
                    }
                } else {
                    switch (char) {
                        case "\"": inString = true; escapeCount = 0; break;
                        case "{": curlyCount++; break;
                        case "}": curlyCount--; break;
                        case "[": squareCount++; break;
                        case "]": squareCount--; break;
                    }
                }
                if (!inString && !curlyCount && !squareCount) {
                    const json = buffer.substring(0, index + 1);

                    buffer = buffer.substring(index + 1);
                    index = 0;
                    try {
                        controller.enqueue(JSON.parse(json));
                    } catch {
                        console.warn("Unable to parse json:", json);
                    }
                }
            }
        },
    });
}
```